# No alive nodes found in your cluster (How to configure elaticsearch with magento2.4.1)

Tags: elasticsearch, magento2.4.1

[image][image]I have installed the magento2.4.1 using CLI, also installed the elastic search (installed elastic search before installing Magento). Now, I am trying to test the connection available in Magento admin panel --> STORES --> Configuration --> CATALOG --> Catalog --> Catalog Search but am getting Connection failed! Test again?. How to resolve this?

I have an active connection with the elastic search port 9200, if I hit localhost:9200 I am getting a successful response.

Comment: do you add ES config in env.php

Comment: i didn't see content of your env.php

Comment: No, please find my env.php code
db' => [
        'table_prefix' => '',
        'connection' => [
            'default' => [
                'host' => 'localhost',
                'dbname' => 'magento2db',
                'username' => 'm2user',
                'password' => 'Qwerty@123',
                'model' => 'mysql4',
                'engine' => 'innodb',
                'initStatements' => 'SET NAMES utf8;',
                'active' => '1',
                'driver_options' => [
                    1014 => false
                ]
            ]
        ]
    ],

Comment: you are using smile elastic search extension ?

Comment: I think no. I have installed it from CLI. with the RPM repository. How to find do I am using smile extension?

Comment: bin/magento module:status check with that command and find it if it is in enable modules

Comment: No, I don't see any module in the name of the smile. Below are the modules enabled related to elastic search.

Magento_Elasticsearch
Magento_Elasticsearch6
Magento_InventoryElasticsearch
Magento_Elasticsearch7

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/117613/discussion-between-yasir-latif-and-ajmalriyaz).

Comment: run netstat -nlp | grep 9200 command and show how many elastic search run . Then kill process by using this command kill -9 <PID_OF_RUNNING_ELASTIC> and also check this coomand ps aux | grep 'elastic' and also kill all process then run start again elastic search

Comment: @Msquare I have added the screenshot to the original post. Only one is running.

Comment: check this link https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/targz.html